# Scala: 'class needs to be abstract' when implementing higher order function

Tags: scala, class, traits

I am trying to ensure that classes (which represent some symbolic math expression) with trait `Func` possess a method that will return a numerical function (implementing the symbolic expression).

```
trait Func {
  def func[T](x: T): T=>Double
}

case class Const(d: Double) extends Func {
  def func[T]: (T=>Double) = (x: T)=>d
}

object Main extends App {
  val c = new Const(3.142)
  val cAt1 = c.func(1.0)
  println(s"c(1.0)=$cAt1") // expected: c(1.0)=3.142
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
[error] /projects/tutdiff/diff.scala:6: class Const needs to be abstract, since method func in trait Func of type [T](x: T)T => Double is not defined
[error] case class Const(d: Double) extends Func {
[error]            ^
```

I am interested in why the implementation of `func` in `Const` doesn't meet the requirements. But also what it is that means a class must be abstract or not (new to Scala).

EDIT: ====================

This is the signature that I was immediately looking for.

```
trait Func {
  def func[T]: T=>Double
}

case class Const(d: Double) extends Func {
  def func[T]: T=>Double = (x: T) => d
}
```

The use of a type parameter `T` should probably be the subject of a follow up question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func` in `Func` has the signature:

```
def func[T](x: T): T => Double
```

Inside `Const`, `func` has a different signature:

```
def func[T]: (T => Double)
```

It no longer takes a parameter of type `T`. Perhaps what you wanted is:

```
def func[T](x: T): (T => Double) = (x: T) => d
```

Although I'm not sure what that actually achieves.